# Exists Eclipse plugin for debug Websphere 7 apps?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, websphere

im new in Websphere 7, and im looking some plugin to debug the apps deployed in WAS 7 using Eclipse. Some one know any plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You dont' need a plugin to do this.

THe standard debugger can hook up to a remove application.

In this case, you would run the WAS 7 in debug mode and make a note of the debug port.

In the Eclipse Debugger view,create a Remote Java Application Configuration(Debug ... -> Remote Java Application and right click for New) and specify the project (from your workspace) and specify the WAS 7 Host and port (the debug port specified in WAS7).

Once you click the Debug, Eclipse would connect to the WAS JVM running in debug mode and you are ready to debug.

This can be used to debug any remote java application.

HTH
Manglu

Comment: Hi Manglu, thanks a lot! Yesterday i find two pages that explains how to connect the Eclipse Debuger with WAS 7.
http://davanum.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/debug-code-running-on-ibm-websphere-using-eclipse-intellij-idea/ http://breathing-java.blogspot.com/2010/04/remote-debugging-with-eclipse.html

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/was-7-0-eclipse-plugin-ibm-websphere-application-server-7-0/) for the details to install an eclipse plugin for WAS 7.0